# Angular $watch function after change variable

Tags: angularjs, watch

I´m trying to build a delayed message box. I observe that `apply` is called when the app is started, as describe in the API docs. But when the observed value is changed, it isn´t called. The `MessageCtrl` is inner controller. Why isn´t `watch` called after changing `message` var?

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('MessageCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.getMessage = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $scope.$parent.message = {text : ""}; 
      $scope.$apply(function() {        
        console.log('message:' + $scope.$parent.message.text);
      });
    }, 2000);
  }
  $scope.getMessage();    
})
.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.message={text:"oi"};
  $scope.$watch("message", function(newValue, oldValue){
      console.log("watch " + $scope.message.text);
  });
});
```

The inner controller MessageCtrl will get the text message and show it for 2 seconds.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="MessageCtrl">
    Message:{{message.text}} 
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell your code does work. You are however using `$apply` incorrectly. `$apply` lets you inform angular that you are changing state outside of the usual methods and that is should thus re-evaluate bindings etc. So you should be using

```
$scope.$apply(function() { $scope.$parent.message = {text: 'new message'}; });
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MessageCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.getMessage = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.$parent.message = {
            text: "new message"
          };
          console.log('message:' + $scope.$parent.message.text);
        });
      }, 2000);
    }
    $scope.getMessage();
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = {
      text: "oi"
    };
    $scope.$watch("message", function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log("watch " + $scope.message.text);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="MessageCtrl">
    Message:{{message.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

One thing of note, you should really use the angular `$timeout` service which allows you to set timeouts in your app, but you don't have to handle calling $apply.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MessageCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.getMessage = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$parent.message = {
          text: "new message"
        };
        console.log('message:' + $scope.$parent.message.text);
      }, 2000);
    }
    $scope.getMessage();
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = {
      text: "oi"
    };
    $scope.$watch("message", function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log("watch " + $scope.message.text);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="MessageCtrl">
    Message:{{message.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$scope.apply` method because setTimeout function is not  angular native function :

```
    setTimeout(function() { 
$scope.apply({
$scope.$parent.message = {text : ""}; $scope.$apply(function() { console.log('message:' + $scope.$parent.message.text); });}) ;}, 2000);
```

Alternatively you can also use `$timeout` inbuilt-service in angular like this :

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('MessageCtrl', function($scope, , $timeout) { $scope.getMessage = function() { $, $timeout(function() { $scope.$parent.message = {text : ""}; $scope.$apply(function() { console.log('message:' + $scope.$parent.message.text); }); }, 2000); } $scope.getMessage(); })
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$timeout` instead `$apply` that executes `$apply implicity`

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('MessageCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.getMessage = function() {
   $timeout(function() {
      $scope.$parent.message = {text : ""}; 
      $scope.$apply(function() {        
        console.log('message:' + $scope.$parent.message.text);
      });
    }, 2000);
  }
  $scope.getMessage();    
})
```